# Http web request The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. twitter timeline

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to fetch my timeline. Here is the outh part that I have taken from my app on twitter. I have resolved authentication error, and it works. But bad request error seems difficult.

```
         var oauth_token = "[REMOVED]";
             var oauth_token_secret = "[REMOVED]";
        var oauth_consumer_key = "[REMOVED]";
        var oauth_consumer_secret = "[REMOVED]";

        var oauth_version = "1.1";
        var oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";
        var oauth_signature = "VgONw0oQ3JoYAuUGNEVt8SLUMUo%3D";
        // unique request details
        var oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(
            new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
        var timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow
            - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var oauth_timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString();

        // message api details
        var status = "Updating status via REST API if this works";
        var resource_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages.json";
        var screen_name = "nouman_engineer";
        // create oauth signature
        var baseFormat = "oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}" +
                        "&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}&screen_name={6}";

        var baseString = string.Format(baseFormat,
                                    oauth_consumer_key,
                                    oauth_nonce,
                                    oauth_signature_method,
                                    oauth_timestamp,
                                    oauth_token,
                                    oauth_version,
                                     Uri.EscapeDataString(screen_name)
                                    );

        baseString = string.Concat("GET&", Uri.EscapeDataString(resource_url), "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(baseString));

        var compositeKey = string.Concat(Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_secret),
                                "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token_secret));

        //string oauth_signature;
        //using (HMACSHA1 hasher = new HMACSHA1(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(compositeKey)))
        //{
        //    oauth_signature = Convert.ToBase64String(
        //        hasher.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(baseString)));
        //}

        // create the request header
        var headerFormat = "OAuth oauth_nonce=\"{0}\", oauth_signature_method=\"{1}\", " +
                           "oauth_timestamp=\"{2}\", oauth_consumer_key=\"{3}\", " +
                           "oauth_token=\"{4}\", oauth_signature=\"{5}\", " +
                           "oauth_version=\"{6}\"";

        var authHeader = string.Format(headerFormat,
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version)
                        );


        // make the request

        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

        var postBody = "screen_name=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(screen_name);//
        resource_url += "?" + postBody;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(resource_url);
        request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;

        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        request.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";


        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        string responseData = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();}}}
```

Error at line:

```
     WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: need an answer not editting

Comment: And you need to not post your OAUTH keys in public.  You're welcome.

Comment: Also, why are you writing your own OAUTH code in 2015 when there are many many libraries that have already solved this problem?

Comment: can you share a link , i did work on fb, for twitter i am totally new , so help me

Comment: Answer 1 solved problem but can you share me built in methods so that i only use console url and fetch results. any helping links

Comment: i got the answer in Answer 1 ,but in need library to solve writting complex outh code problem can any body share libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem solved guarantee

```
     var oAuthConsumerKey = "key";
          var oAuthConsumerSecret =     "key";
              var oAuthUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";
         var screenname = "nouman_engineer";

 // Do the Authenticate
                 var authHeaderFormat = "Basic {0}";

                       var authHeader = string.Format(authHeaderFormat,
Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthConsumerKey) + ":" +
Uri.EscapeDataString((oAuthConsumerSecret)))
                         ));

    var postBody = "grant_type=client_credentials";

   HttpWebRequest authRequest =    (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(oAuthUrl);
    authRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
    authRequest.Method = "POST";
authRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
authRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip |    DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

    using (Stream stream = authRequest.GetRequestStream())
  {
   byte[] content = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postBody);
stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
  }

  authRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");

    WebResponse authResponse = authRequest.GetResponse();
   // deserialize into an object
     TwitAuthenticateResponse twitAuthResponse;
       using (authResponse)
       {
        using (var reader = new         StreamReader(authResponse.GetResponseStream())) {
      JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
     var objectText = reader.ReadToEnd();
    twitAuthResponse =     JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TwitAuthenticateResponse>(objectText);
}
  }

     // Do the timeline
     var timelineFormat =          "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=  {0}&include_rts=1&exclude_replies=1&count=5";
      var timelineUrl = string.Format(timelineFormat, screenname);
         HttpWebRequest timeLineRequest =   (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(timelineUrl);
    var timelineHeaderFormat = "{0} {1}";
   timeLineRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization",    string.Format(timelineHeaderFormat, twitAuthResponse.token_type,     twitAuthResponse.access_token));
    timeLineRequest.Method = "Get";
    WebResponse timeLineResponse = timeLineRequest.GetResponse();
      var timeLineJson = string.Empty;
     using (timeLineResponse)
      {
 using (var reader = new          StreamReader(timeLineResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
       timeLineJson = reader.ReadToEnd();
   }
      }
      }
```

and do something by your self 
and please comment only links and helping meterials donot talk only

Comment: Hey, what is TwitAuthenticateResponse here?

Comment: i have same doubt what is TwitAuthenticateResponse here?